Distance of a point $x_0$ of a subspace of a normed space.
Suppose $Y$ is a closed subspace of a normed space $X$ and $Y \neq X$. We consider $x_0 \in X$. We consider $δ = d(x_0, Y) = \inf ( ||x_0 - y||: y \in Y )$. If we prove that $δ=0$ then that means that $x_0 \in Y$? I don't see why this can't be true. If we didn't know that $Y$ is closed then I think it could be $δ=0$ and $x_0 \notin Y$, in the case that $Y$ was open. Or am I wrong?
Thank you for any help.

Wait a minute. If $Y$ is not closed it could well be that it is not open, either. Your last statement seems to imply the opposite, and that's a typical mistake, hope you are aware of this. As for the actual question, that inf being 0 means that there is a sequence in $Y$ such that...

The only vector subspace of a normed space $X$ that is open is $X$ itself (which, by the record, is closed). Of course, the vector subspaces of $X$ that aren't closed are not open either. For any such subspace you'll have $d(x_0,Y)=0$ for all $x_0\in \overline Y\setminus Y$.

My last statement means that if I don't know for sure that $Y$ is closed then I can't conclude that $x_0 \in Y $.

Another property is that if $Y$ is closed and $\delta >0$ then there does not necessarily exist $y\in Y$ such that $|y-x_0|=\delta$.

Yes, if $d (x_0, Y) = $ when $Y$ is closed, then $x_0 \in Y$. You can easily show this as follows. Suppose $d (x_0, Y) = \inf \{ ||x_0 - y||: y \in Y \} = 0$. Consider any basis element $B_d (x_0, \varepsilon)$ about $x_0$, with $\varepsilon > 0$. There must be some element $y_\varepsilon \in Y$ such that $y_\varepsilon \in B_d (x_0, \varepsilon)$, where $d$ is the metric induced by the norm $||\cdot||$. If not, then $\varepsilon$ would be a lower bound on $\{ ||x_0 - y||: y \in Y \}$ that is greater than $0$, a contradiction. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, $x_0 \in \text{Cl} Y$. Since $Y$ is closed, $\text{Cl} Y = Y$; therefore, $x_0 \in Y$, as desired.

Nice, thank you very much.
